# How can I map an array of objects to MenuItems for a MUI Select Field

Tags: javascript, arrays, material-ui

I have an array `fieldChoices`.  I want to map the values of field choices to create the options for an MUI Select field, but I have not been able to do this successfully.

This is how I populate `fieldChoices`:

```
fieldChoices = {
    choices: filtered_status.map(function (item) {
        return {
            id: item.IntakeID,
            title: item.Title,
        };
    }),
};
```

Populated, `fieldChoices` follows this structure: `{choices: [{id: 123, title: "321"}, {id: 456, title: "654"}]`

This is how I am trying to map the MenuItems:

```
<TextField value={ID || ""} select>
    {fieldChoices?.choices?.map((index, e) => {
        return (
            <MenuItem key={index} value={e}>
                {e}
            </MenuItem>
        );
    })}
</TextField>
```

Comment: What error or unexpected behavior are you getting?

Comment: Right now, there is no value and no options appearing in the Select field.  There is no value because there is no options displayed.  There are no error messages.  I want the id's in `choices` to serve as the value of the options, with `id + title` as the displayed text.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to map is the current element and the second argument is the index. Note: it is better to use the id as the key rather than the index.

```js
{fieldChoices?.choices?.map((e, index) => {
    return (
        <MenuItem key={e.id} value={e.id}>
            {e.id + e.title}
        </MenuItem>
    );
})}
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately the issue still persists.

Comment: @CiaranCrowley You should probably use the [Select component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/), not `TextField`.

Comment: The same issue is present with Select component.  How would you map field choices to the MenuItems if field choices looked like this:
`[123, 123, 123, 123]`?

Comment: @CiaranCrowley What's the expected result?

Comment: @CiaranCrowley Also, you can see the code in my answer working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-danny-gzmg59?file=/demo.tsx). There is no issue.

Comment: Before fieldChoices is created, I am calling an API to `const response`.  `response` is then converted into json before being filtered to meet certain conditions.  This is stored in `const filtered_status`.  Then `fieldChoices` is populated with the code in my question.

Comment: @CiaranCrowley If your code still doesn't work, it will help to provide a [mre]. I cannot reproduce any issue.